# Extract All <xxxx> Tags From a String

Tags: java, android, regex

I've been trying to extract "pointers" in a string to replace them with actual values using regex. The source string is pulled from the database, and can be of a couple of forms - I hope you can see what I mean:

The string I need to extract the information from is of the form `<X Description> blah blah <Y> blah blah blah <Z Differentdescription>`

I need to extract

```
<X Description>,
<Y>,
<Z Differentdescription>
```

from the string (so that they can be replaced with actual values before being displayed to the user).

I thought something like this would work: `(<[XYZ]( \w+)?>)+`

However, it only captures the "`<X Description>`" tag (how it's meant to), as well as " Description" (which I don't quite understand), and doesn't capture either of `<Y>` or `<Z Description>`

I'm not trying to parse XML or HTML (which I know is frowned upon with regex), and there aren't going to be any nested tags, I just need to get the sequence of matches.

Ultimately this is going to be used in an android app, but I need to get the regex working first!

Comment: Can we see your code? It is hard to correct it if we don't know how it looks.

Comment: I've been using an online regex tester at [link](http://regex101.com/) to try and get the pattern sorted before I put it into my code, so it's not the Java part that's the problem, unless the regex tester isn't bringing back what it should.

Comment: Your regex should work. You could modify like this though..  `(<[XYZ](?: \w+)?>)+`.  You just need to make sure is a 'global' match.  You may need to use a `g` flag.

Comment: Your regex looks fine (you just needed to add `g` flag to make regex engine look for global matches). Try it on other places like http://regexpal.com/ http://www.regexplanet.com/ http://regexr.com/

Comment: Does it help: http://regex101.com/r/uT3gX9

Comment: Thanks for all of the replies - I didn't realise the g was necessary, and hadn't put it in the second box on the regex tester. Feeling like a muppet, but thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex, `(<[XYZ]( \w+)?>)+` is close to doing what you want, but the second set of brackets (i.e. `( \w+)`) also forms a capture.

If you change your regex to be `(<[XYZ](?: \w+)?>)`, it should work correctly. `?:` makes the brackets non-capturing.

> and doesn't capture either of `<Y>` or `<Z Description>`

This is because you're not using the `g` option for your regular expression, so it's terminating after the first match.

Answer (score 1):

you can use positive look behind and positive look ahead like this:

```
String str = "<X Description> blah blah <Y> blah blah blah <Z Differentdescription>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=<)[\\w\\s]+?(?=>)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

1. (?<=<)[\w\s]+?  - will match `<`  followed by any word or space
2. [\w\s]+?(?=>)   - will match any word/space followed by `>`

output:

```
X Description
Y
Z Differentdescription
```